# .NET Core 3.1 MapControllerRoute causing urls without areas to not load properly

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have these 2 route patterns:

```
config.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{Controller=Home}/{Action=Index}/{id?}");
config.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{Controller=Home}/{Action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Since my application mainly uses areas, all of the urls with areas work fine.
Example:

```
[Area("Configuration")]
[TypeFilter(typeof(ValidateAdministratorFilter))]
public class ApiKeyApplicationController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

    }
}
```

The above URL will look like this in a @Url.Action: /Configuration/ApiKeyApplication/Index only

However, if I have a url without an area, like this:

```
[Route("/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class ConfirmController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult ConfirmDetails()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Modals/ConfirmDetails.cshtml");
    }
}
```

The above URL will look like this in a @Url.Action: /Confirm only

If I try to set it to /Confirm/ConfirmDetails, it will show a 404 error

Is this due to my routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to delete the route in your `ConfirmController`

Delete this :

```
[Route("/[controller]")]
```

Or you can change it to:

```
 [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
```